# Crystal Reports is displaying different dates than what is stored in Data

Tags: crystal-reports

Seems like there must be a simple solution to this problem. I am using dates related to data to group the data within a group header. The dates stored in data are:

```
01/01/1900 00:00:00
08/07/2000 00:00:00
26/11/2002 00:00:00
03/03/2003 00:00:00
01/03/2011 00:00:00
10/06/2011 00:00:00
27/04/2012 00:00:00
```

However the group titles displayed are:

```
31/12/1899 
02/07/2000
24/11/2002
02/03/2003
01/11/2009
11/04/2010
15/08/2010
27/02/2011
05/06/2011
03/07/2011
22/04/2012
```

Now there should be 11 groups, so i assume the browse data is just not displaying all the dates within the data. 
Has anyone seen this before? These dates are very important, so I have to find a way to make them correct.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a culture related issue in your report. have you tried to format the date in crystal report. This [link](http://www.crystalreportsexperts.com/general/Q_26756372-Problem-in-Crystal-Report-output-date.jsp) and [this](http://forums.devarticles.com/net-development-43/crystal-reports-for-vs-net-globalization-6168.html) may give you some idea